Renderring React Components in Laravel Livewire Stack?
I'm wondering if there's a way to render react components in Livewire. I just got started with Laravel and I have little-to-no experience in using the Livewire stack. I have a messaging application implemented in react and would like to integrate this to a laravel livewire project that I am doing, what I am trying to ask is basically what are the extra steps that I need to do to accomplish the task?
I could not find a tutorial or any online video that discusses this to a level that I can understand however, I tried doing it by creating simple react components and rendering it using:
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8 p-6">
        <p>Discover page</p>
        @inertia
    </div>

And when I load the page I get the error message Undefined variable $page referring to @inertia line

You can check out this : https://github.com/ijpatricio/mingle . I haven't used it but a youtube video demonstrate that we can : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Pj87lvjV-0
